# codeigniter php.ini allow_url_fopen=1

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-2, cpanel

ini parameter allow_url_fopen=0 to allow_url_fopen=1
but when to cpanel set custom php.ini create and .htacsess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|sitemap.xml|php.ini|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_suphp.c>

suPHP_ConfigPath /home/myuser/public_html/

</IfModule>
```

and php.ini to

```
allow_url_fopen=1
```

but pagee not load or error 500?

Comment: Did you check the Apache error log?

Comment: Apache error log in the trump card for 500 error. See that /etc/httpd/logs/error_log.

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct php.ini value you should use...

allow_url_fopen = On

hope it helps